# How to remove checked checkbox if all sub check boxes are unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have group of checkboxes (Sub1,Sub2,Sub3) and One main check box. If check any sub check box the main checkbox have to be checked. If all the sub check boxes are uncheck then only the main check box have to be unchecked,if atleast one checkbox is checked then the main checkbox have to be checked.My code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
        var chk1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='1']");

        var chk2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='2']");
        var chk3 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='3']");
        var chk4 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='4']");

        chk2.on('change', function() {
            chk1.prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        chk3.on('change', function() {
            chk1.prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        chk4.on('change', function() {
            chk1.prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="user_name">Main1
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="one" class="user_name">sub-2
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="one" class="user_name">sub-3
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="one" class="user_name">sub-4
        <br>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a single click handler where you can check whether any of the sub items is checked

```js
$(function() {
  var $checks = $("input.user_name:not(.main)"),
    $main = $('input.user_name.main');
  $checks.change(function() {
    $main.prop('checked', $checks.is(':checked'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="user_name main">Main1
<br>
<br>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="one" class="user_name">sub-2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="one" class="user_name">sub-3
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="one" class="user_name">sub-4
<br>
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, apt answer. What if I have another set of Main2 with (Sub-5,Sub-6,Sub-7). what changes do we need to do for another group of check boxes.

Comment: @GaneshSudarsan you need to share the html structure

Comment: Hi Arun , After checking any Sub1,Sub2,Sub3 checkboxes. Main is checked. If I uncheck the Main checkbox the remaining subcheckboxes remains checked. how to make uncheck the Subcheck boxes if we un check the Main Checkbox can you help me what to do? in this [http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cpncz12L/2/]

Comment: Hi Arun, By submiting a page how to validate that atleast one check box is  checked, if any check box is checked in all checkboxes then the form have to go further process other wise not, in this link :[http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cpncz12L/3/]

Answer (score 1):

You can use your common `user_name` class to achieve this whenever a `change` event happens on them. Try this:

```
$('.user_name').change(function () {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var $siblings = $checkbox.siblings('.user_name');

    if ($checkbox.is(':first-child')) {
        $siblings.prop('checked', $checkbox.prop('checked'));
    } else {
        $siblings.first().prop('checked', $siblings.not(':first-child').length == $siblings.filter(':checked').length);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ln35LeL/)

Also note that you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute which is invalid - the `id` should be unique to an element with the document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an OR statement. You can do it exhaustively or within a loop. This solution is of the first type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

      $(window).load(function(){
        var chk1 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='1']");

        var chk2 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='2']");
        var chk3 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='3']");
        var chk4 = $("input[type='checkbox'][value='4']");

        chk2.on('change', function(){
          chk1.prop('checked',(chk2.checked || chk3.checked || chk4.checked) );
        });
        chk3.on('change', function(){
          chk1.prop('checked',(chk2.checked || chk3.checked || chk4.checked) );
        });
        chk4.on('change', function(){
          chk1.prop('checked',(chk2.checked || chk3.checked || chk4.checked) );
        });
      }); 
    </script>
  </head>
...
```